# $(ProjectName) and $(TargetName) MSBuild macros not working

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Stduio 2015 Community Edition. I have loaded a C# project and want to configure it to use shadow building, so that source files are not messed up with any binaries or intermediate build files. Tried to set the [output]/[intermediate output] directory paths of the C# project using the VS UI - the only UI-editable output path is the "bin" one and it doesn't accept [MSBuild macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx). Then I've unloaded the project and manually edited it. Also set the IntermediateOutputPath which is not available in the VS UI when using C# project, but when using C++ one all such kind of directories are editable.
Currently, the OutputPath is set to:
`<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)..\build_$(SolutionName)_$(Configuration)_$(Platform)\$(ProjectName)</OutputPath>`

`$(ProjectName)` is empty for some reason. Tried `$(TargetName)` (it is not correct to use it but just for the test) but it is empty, too. Any suggestions?

Comment: *[Don't use `$(ProjectDir)`, but instead use `$(MSBuildProjectDir`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647373/when-does-msbuild-set-the-projectname-property/2652555#2652555)*.

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to import `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` - like suggested in another answer.
First of all - it will lead to additional warning like

```
Warning MSB4011: "Microsoft.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported again. ...
```

But additionally to that if you try to edit pre-/post- build Visual studio will crash.
(Observed in Visual studio 2019, 16.7.7 version)

Better to use `$(MSBuildProjectName)` macro instead of `$(ProjectName)` - works identically.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that some of the MSBuild properties like ProjectName are set after the following line in your .csproj file.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

After this line you can access all variables.

Comment: In turn, this file depends on other properties, such as `OutputPath`, to be set. These are set by a number of `PropertyGroup` tags in the project file, one for each project configuration (configuration|platform). So these must come first, followed by the import, followed by the `PropertyGroup` which defines the post-build event.

Comment: Yes, and *[don't use `$(ProjectDir)`, but instead use `$(MSBuildProjectDir`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647373/when-does-msbuild-set-the-projectname-property/2652555#2652555)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: your comment should be the answer.

Comment: Agreed. @PeterMortensen please consider promoting your comments to an actual answer here.

Comment: Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks