# VS2017 Post-Build Event

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xcopy, post-build-event

Okay, I am going nuts here.  I have searched and tried every command I can find to try to copy the result of my build to another directory on the network.  So basically I want to build the project, then have the created .DLL copied and overwrite the one on the network.  Here is my latest try that I found online:

```
xcopy /i /e /s /y /f $(TargetPath) "\\SERVER\Folder1\Folder2\Binaries"
```

This just does not seem to work!  Can somebody give me an example of how I can write this line that will work?

Comment: Put "double quotes" around $(TargetPath) so it still works when the project directory name contains spaces.

Comment: When I put double quotes around $(TargetPath) it doesn't seem to see the directory, and shows empty quotes with a "Code 4" error:

The command "xcopy /i /e /s /y /f "" "\\SERVER\Folder1\Folder2\Binaries"" exited with code 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(ProjectName) and $(TargetName) MSBuild macros not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126926/projectname-and-targetname-msbuild-macros-not-working)