# What is the difference between $(ProjectDir) and $(MSBuildProjectDir)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Investigating a build problem that only occurs on our build server, I was surprised to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652555/29152) point out there is both a `$(ProjectDir)` and a `$(MSBuildProjectDir)`, the former sometimes not available.

What is the difference in general? Should I always be using `$(MSBuildXXX)` versions of properties if available? Why use `$(ProjectDir)` in the first  place?

Contrary to advice in the other Q&A, I'm sometimes  seeing `$(MSBuildProjectDir) = ''`.

Answer (score 6):

As your linked answer says `$(ProjectDir)` is only available after Microsoft.Common.Targets has been imported, while `$(MSBuildProjectDir)` is a reserved property in MSBuild itself.

So using the `$(MSBuildXXX)` properties will ensure that they are always available to you without needing to import all the necessary references.