# How can I build a native DLL as part of a .NET build process?

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I am building a project in C# to interface with a C++ library. Because I want this to be cross platform I am using .NET Core RC3 though I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Right now I have the cpp files in my project and I have a `PreBuildEvent` like

```
<PreBuildEvent>
   gcc -c -fPIC -std=c++11  "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\cfile.cpp" -o"$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\cfile.o"
  gcc -shared -o "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\cfile.dll" "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\cfile.o" -lstdc++
</PreBuildEvent>
```

The DLL gets built, and then copied to the output directory. Then I use PInvoke to communicate with it.

This part works. Then I add a test project that references the first project. The part that doesn't work is when I try to do `dotnet test`.

Then it says

```
gcc : error : ProjectName\cfile.cpp: No such file or directory
```

I guess `$(SolutionDir)` must not be set in this case, or something.

If I change the project to a command line application, and do `dotnet run` that doesn't work either.

`$(ProjectDir)` doesn't seem to be available in this case either in the `PreBuildEvent` or the `PostBuildEvent`.

What's the best way to set this up so it works?

Comment: Your prebuild event is in a project file, which likely has a fixed location relative to the solution (else you wouldn't be able to use SolutionDir in the first place). So specify the path to the cpp file relative to $(ProjectDir) instead.

Comment: For some reason $(ProjectDir) evaluates to nothing in both the prebuild and postbuild events.

Comment: The problem also occurs if I change the project to a console application and try to do `dotnet run` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` should be used instead ... 
[When does MSBuild set the $(ProjectName) property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647373/when-does-msbuild-set-the-projectname-property)

This seems to work for all combinations of build, test, and run in Visual Studio and from the command line.